# How to control/drive/interact a PyQt GUI from command line in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, user-interface, command-line, pyqt5

I have a GUI application created with PyQt and I would like to be able to control it also from the python terminal through a kind of internal API.

Ideas :

- Using the main terminal : impossible since that it is blocked by the QApplication (by app.exec_())
- Starting the GUI in another thread to free the main one : impossible, the QApplications have to be executed in the main one.
- ???

I don't want an 'in-app' terminal.

Do you have any other ideas ?

Comment: If you want to control an already open GUI application, they you could have a second program that allows you to send commands to the GUI application via sockets or inter-process communication.

Answer (score 3):

> Using the main terminal : impossible since that it is blocked by the
>   QApplication (by app.exec_())

You can omit `app.exec()` if you are within a Python terminal and it will not be blocking. As explained [here](https://www.riverbankcomputing.com/static/Docs/PyQt5/python_shell.html) this works because...

> PyQt5 installs an input hook (using PyOS_InputHook) that processes
>   events when an interactive interpreter is waiting for user input. This
>   means that you can, for example, create widgets from the Python shell
>   prompt, interact with them, and still being able to enter other Python
>   commands.

For example, enter the following in the Python shell to have a working Qt widget and a non-blocking REPL simultaniously.

```
$> python
Python 3.7.6 | packaged by conda-forge | (default, Jan  7 2020, 22:05:27)
[Clang 9.0.1 ] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QWidget
>>> a = QApplication([])
>>> w = QWidget()
>>> w.show()
>>> w.raise_()
```

IPython has similar functionality. If you start it with `ipython --gui=qt`, or type `%gui qt` in the terminal you get the same effect...

```
$> ipython
Python 3.7.6 | packaged by conda-forge | (default, Jan  7 2020, 22:05:27)
Type 'copyright', 'credits' or 'license' for more information
IPython 7.11.1 -- An enhanced Interactive Python. Type '?' for help.

In [1]: %gui qt

In [2]: from PyQt5 import QtWidgets

In [3]: win = QtWidgets.QPushButton("click me")

In [4]: win.show()

In [5]: win.raise_()
```

I recommend to use IPython because it's better suited for interactive work and it will work with PySide (perhaps regular Python and PySide will also work; I didn't check).

See also my earlier answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45664602/matplotlib-interactive-event-loops)

Finally, even though this works I don't know how good the performance is. It's a good solution for a hobby project but if you have many users I would consider to implement an 'in-app' terminal or some form of inter-process communication.

Answer (score 2):

Depending on what you seem to ask, you want to implement something similar to Native Messaging Protocol<sub>([Chrome](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/nativeMessaging), [Mozilla](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Add-ons/WebExtensions/Native_messaging))</sub>, if so, then you should use [`QWinEventNotifier`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qwineventnotifier.html) or [`QSocketNotifier`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qsocketnotifier.html) depending on the OS to detect if it was written on the console.

Based on [my previous answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59348696/6622587) I created the following example where the user writes in the console some phrase and press <kbd>Enter</kbd> then that phrase is shown in the QLabel (I have only tested my example in Linux).

```py
import platform
import sys

from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets


class NativeMessenger(QtCore.QObject):
    messageChanged = QtCore.pyqtSignal(str)

    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super().__init__(parent)

        self.m_qin = QtCore.QFile()

        self.m_qin.open(
            sys.stdin.fileno(), QtCore.QIODevice.ReadOnly | QtCore.QIODevice.Unbuffered
        )

        if platform.system() == "Windows":
            import win32api

            if sys.platform == "win32":
                import os
                import msvcrt

                if platform.python_implementation() == "PyPy":
                    os.fdopen(fh.fileno(), "wb", 0)
                else:
                    msvcrt.setmode(sys.stdin.fileno(), os.O_BINARY)

            self.m_notifier = QtCore.QWinEventNotifier(
                win32api.GetStdHandle(win32api.STD_INPUT_HANDLE)
            )

        else:
            self.m_notifier = QtCore.QSocketNotifier(
                sys.stdin.fileno(), QtCore.QSocketNotifier.Read, self
            )

        self.m_notifier.activated.connect(self.readyRead)

    @QtCore.pyqtSlot()
    def readyRead(self):
        line = self.m_qin.readLine().data().decode().strip()
        self.messageChanged.emit(line)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)

    w = QtWidgets.QLabel(alignment=QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter)
    w.resize(640, 480)
    w.show()

    messenger = NativeMessenger()
    messenger.messageChanged.connect(w.setText)

    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Output:

```
Stack Overflow
```

[image]

The above can be taken as the basis for implementing your API.

---

Although another approach is to have 2 applications where a CLI controls the GUI by communicating through sockets and other protocols such as IPC (dbus, etc.), ZeroMQ, MQTT, etc.

Comment: @S.Nick 32 or 64 bits?

Comment: Windows 64  bits